# $f(x)$ is continuous for all $x$ if $a=$?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

If $$f(x) = \begin{cases}x+1, & x \leq 1 \\
          3x+ax^2, & x>1\end{cases}$$

Then $f(x)$ is continuous for all $x$ if $a=$?

Please help me...

Comment: It must be that $$\;\lim_{x\to 1^-}f(x)=\lim_{x\to 1^+}f(x)\ldots$$

Answer (score 1):

As @DonAntonio writes it must be that the limit approaching $1$ from the left (this is what the notation $\displaystyle \lim_{x\rightarrow 1^{-}}f(x)$ means) must be the same as the limit approaching $1$ from the right. A continuous function is one that has no jumps in it, so that if $x+1 \neq 3x + ax^{2}$ at $1$ the function $f(x)$ is not continuous

Comment: BrabazonThanks, but do you have a clear procedure or formula to explain when f(X) is continuous for all x if a=?

Comment: The procedure is to check that the limit exists at each point and is equal to the function evaluated at the point, i.e. $\lim_{x\rightarrow 1^{-}}f(x) = \lim_{x\rightarrow 1^{+}}f(x) = f(1)$. As I hinted at in my response this requires that $x+1 = 3x + ax^{2}$ when $x=1$. For an introduction to what continuity means the textbook 'Numerical Analysis' by Burden and Faires is a very good text